# ng-repeat filter by function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use a filter on my ng-repeat that is a function that has a parameter passed in, however the filter doesn't seem to work.

This is the filter function that i am using. It compares 2 arrays to see what matches in each then should return true or false.

```
$scope.ifinfav1 = function(f){
  return e.indexOf(f) !== -1;
};
```

This is my HTML where the filter is being used.

```
<ion-view view-title="Favourites">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
        <ion-item id="fav" class="item-icon-right" collection-repeat="office in offices|filter:ifinfav1(office.id)" ng-controller="ModalCtrl" ng-click="openModal(office.id); lastview(office.id);">
            <p>{{office.id}}</p>
            <p id="details">{{office.LocAddressLine1 + ", " + office.LocAddressLine2 + ", " + office.LocCity + ", " + office.LocCountryDescription + ", " + office.LocZipPostalCode}}</p>
            <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': liked(office.id), 'icon ion-android-star-outline': liked(office.id)}" ng-click="togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
        </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can not choose** what **arguments** are passed to the function you use as a predicate to your filter.
That is, you can **not** do:

```
<p ng-repeat="office in offices | filter:isInFavourites(offices.id)">
```

You can only specify the function itself, not the arguments that are gonna be passed to it when invoked. Thus, only the following is valid:

```
<p ng-repeat="office in offices | filter:isInFavourites">
```

As specified in **AngularJS's** [documentation for `filter` (link)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

> The function is called for each element of the array, with **the element**, its index, and the entire array itself as arguments.

What's interesting here for you is the **element** itself, the first argument your function is being passed. You simply have to update it to work with your `office` objects instead of their `id`s.
For example:

```
$scope.ifinfav1 = function(office){
  return e.indexOf(office.id) !== -1;
};
```

... would do wonders!

Here's a link to [a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gof0rw2y/1/) illustrating my suggestion with sample data.

Comment: just a note (and I am using *filter* in a generic sense):  You can pass additional parameters to filters via this syntax, thereby allowing you to specifying to some degree - `<p ng-repeat="office in offices | myCustomerFilter : arg1 : arg2">` and the custom filter function would be `function( obj, arg1, arg2 ){ ... }`

Comment: @jusopi That is true when actually declaring a `filter`, which the OP isn't doing here. He's simply using a function as a predicate, a plain function that isn't registered as a potential filter in his app.

Comment: correct, I just wanted to present the information.  If he can make a custom filter *stateless* then he can avoid dirtying up his controller.

Comment: Oh yeah, fair enough, that's actually a great recommendation, thanks ^^